# How to return the real value (unsigned char array in my case) and not a pointer from a function in C++?

Tags: c++

First of all, I am using C++ and I am a newbie on it. I have an interface with exposes a method `unsigned char * readRequest()`. All of my classes inherit this interface and implement the `unsigned char * readRequest()` in its way (dealing with float, string, int, double, char), but return `unsigned char *`. Below are some of my implementations of `readRequest()` that converts float to `unsigned char *`. 
Edited: I am returning a pointer to a local variable and this is an undefined behavior. How do I return the real value in C++?

```
unsigned char * readRequest() {
    float preCent = distanceCentimeters();
    std::cout << preCent << std::endl; // print correct result
    unsigned char buf[4];
    memcpy(buf, &preCent, sizeof(preCent));

    float result;
    memcpy(&result, buf, sizeof(result));
    std::cout << result << std::endl; // print correct result

    return buf;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char *readRequestArray;
    readRequestArray = (unsigned char*) readRequest();
    float converted_back;
    memcpy(&converted_back, readRequestArray, sizeof converted_back);
    std::cout << converted_back; // ERROR due to return a pointer to local variable
}
```

Output and error:

```
24.2882
jN�A 
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You should try stepping through your code, line by line, in your debugger. Pay attention to variable values and control flow along the way. When it crashes, also look at the call stack to see how you got there.

Comment: Returning a raw pointer from a function  is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: You should be using a `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` or `std::vector<unsigned char>` (or `std::byte` in place of `unsigned char`) if you want to return data from the function.

Comment: I was using `char _value[];` and returning `char *`. I am concerning about the time execution. If `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` does not increase the time execution do you have any example of using it?

Comment: It doesn't increase the execution time, it just protects against memory leaks. No cost.

Comment: @NathanOliver and @Matthieu Brucher. I tested using `std::vector<unsigned char>` and my buffer increased 10 times to return the value. So, it is why I am using `unsigned char array`. However, I edited the question to return the real value of the local variable, not the pointer. If you have some idea to help me I will appreciate that. I guess this is the main problem in my function and it is why I am getting `Segmentation fault`. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to local variables. This doesn't work and will be raised by your compiler in the warnings.

Allocated data and return a unique pointer, or just simply use a string, as you are passing memory management to the caller. You are in C++, use C++ style code, not C (`printf` and others).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2266772/matthieu-brucher - So what should I return? I have another class that implements `readRequest()` function and returns `unsigned char*`. This function is converting string to an `unsigned char array` and it is working. I used this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52737355/2096986

Comment: A `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[] >`. That's the contract that modern c++ gives to enforce proper memory management.

Comment: And both methods should return this. You cannot have a child class that returns a managed array and another an unmanaged array. It's bad design. Either you return a naked pointer that tells the user that he doesn't have to free the memory, or you return a unique pointer. There must not be any confusion on who is responsible for the memory.

Comment: I have never worked with unique_ptr. Could you please give a help on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52739477/how-to-return-copy-values-of-an-unique-ptrunsigned-char ?