# Returning unsigned char array in a function but not the pointer

Tags: c++

I am implementing a simple class in C++ which have only one attribute that has to be `unsigned char array` and two methods, one get and one set. I am struggling to define this unsigned char array. I defined the attributed as a pointer, but the get method cannot return a pointer because this is an undefined behavior. So what should I return? and address? If I use `&` the class does not compile.

Ho to implement this class to not return a pointer to the local ´unsigned char array´?

ps: I am not using `std::vector<unsigned char>` or other types because it increases 10 time to return the value. With char array I got 0.005 milliseconds and with `std::vector<unsigned char>` I got 0.07 milliseconds.

```
class SkinnyBuffer {
private:
    unsigned char* _value;
public:
    ~SkinnyBuffer();
    SkinnyBuffer();
    void setBufferValue(unsigned char value[]);
    unsigned char& getBufferValue();;
};

#include "utils/SkinnyBuffer.h"

SkinnyBuffer::~SkinnyBuffer() {
}
SkinnyBuffer::SkinnyBuffer() {
}
void SkinnyBuffer::setBufferValue(unsigned char value[]) {
    _value = value;
}
unsigned char SkinnyBuffer::getBufferValue() {
    return _value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more reasonable approach. Although, it is not good either. You should implement the constructor and destructor. The  way to do it is to return a pointer. You can't return an entire array. Although you should keep an extra field for the size of the array.

```
class SkinnyBuffer {
private:
    unsigned char* _value;
public:
    ~SkinnyBuffer();
    SkinnyBuffer();
    void setBufferValue(unsigned char value[], size_t n);
    unsigned char* getBufferValue();
};

// imagine this is the cpp file down here

void SkinnyBuffer::setBufferValue(unsigned char value[], size_t n) {
    if(_value != nullptr)
      delete [] _value;
    _size = n; // assume _size is a field
    _value = new unsigned char[_size];
    std::copy(value, value + n, _value);
}

unsigned char* SkinnyBuffer::getBufferValue() {
    return _value;
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: you assume it's a buffer of text. If not then `strlen` and `strcpy` are wrong and adding a null sentinel is pointless

Comment: Yes, I'm assuming a buffer of text because it is common, just to make a concrete example. Like you said, if it is just to be used as a buffer is just better to use std::copy and not to include the null character of course.

Comment: I would argue that a buffer is more commonly non-text, because for text you'd use a string ;)

Comment: True, but sometimes you want to implement your own string class for fun. For a common buffer then the size of the array must be provided.

Comment: Indeed, all true.

Comment: @blade - the `std::strlen` does not work with `unsigned char value[]`

Comment: fixed to a generic buffer, but you pass the size of the array though

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little underspecified but does open up some possibilities.

First of all, you need to decide these things:

- Do you want to store an array, or a pointer?

  - Currently you're storing a pointer, though it may point to an array.
- Do you want to return an array, or a pointer to its first element?

  - You can't return an array
  - You *can* return a pointer in this case (it's not UB, but `getBufferValue` needs to return a `unsigned char*` in order for this to compile), but do you want to?

If the bounds of the `SkinnyBuffer` can change, then storing a pointer to some dynamically allocated memory is appropriate. You should instead use a `std::vector` for this purpose, and accessing a vector is not slower despite your claims — you must have accidentally copied it somewhere or done some other inefficient thing. So you can explore that further.

As for returning values, well again this depends on what you want. It may be more logical to implement an `operator[]` that provides element-like access to the buffer. But, then, why wrap the vector at all? Just have a vector!

If you do want to return a pointer, you won't be able to assign this to an object of array type (despite what Robert's answer claims); you'd have to use `std::copy` (or a related technique) to copy its elements one at a time. This is a limitation inherited from C, which does not permit direct array assignment. Also note that the returned pointer will be "weak" but also not clearly describe this to the programmer writing code at the call site, which is dangerous; a smart pointer would make this better.

Finally, the core of your problem is that this all applies to `setBufferValue`, too. Your input into the class just copies a pointer, and who knows what that points to? Again, a vector will make your life much easier.

Ultimately there are plenty of choices here and the "right" choice depends on your actual requirements and what you want to do with this data.

Comment: I assume that the OP returned a vector by value, which should be a lot slower than returning just a pointer to the first element of an array. (One *should* probably instead return a *reference* to the vector, also to maintain the per-reference semantics, which would not be slower.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Indeed.

Comment: Ok. I will do with vectors and rephrase the question. thanks

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez inb4 please don't substantially modify the premise of the question - clarify it but if you have a new piece of code it warrants a new question (after a few hours/days working with it, of course!)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - coping using `_array = std::vector<unsigned char>(str.data(), str.data() + str.length());` is still 10 times slower than the solution of @blade.

Comment: @FelipeOliveiraGutierrez Right, which is why nobody suggested doing that. Why do you need to copy anything? If that's a requirement, you need to mention it up-front in the question. Of course, copying into a vector vs copying into an array carries the same cost anyway. I'm telling you: using a vector does not inherently carry a performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `setBufferValue` will set `_value` to point to the same address of the passed array. It will not copy it, so be careful dealing with it

Now, for `getBufferValue`, it must be declared as:

```
unsigned char * getBufferValue();
```

and

```
unsigned char * SkinnyBuffer::getBufferValue() {
```